# Cypress test being flakey on a MUI date input

Tags: material-ui, cypress

I am testing a form in React using Cypress and am running in to issues with one of the tests which enters a date in to a MUI date input. The test will pass several times in a row but then will fail on subsequent runs. When the test fails it is because it types the `yyyy` first and not the `mm` and `dd`. I can't quite figure out why it types the date correctly and then it types the year first on subsequent tries.

The Cypress command is as follows...

```
Cypress.Commands.add('fillDate', (name, date) => {
const date = cy.get(input[name="${name}"]);
dateField.type(date);
dateField.should('have.value', date)
}


cy.fillDate('name', '01/01/2025')
```

I expected the test to enter a full date in `mm/dd/yyyy`

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not follow the standard Cypress convention, so that is probably why it is flaky.

You can try to use the "fluid" approach to constructing the query code, something like this:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('fillDate', (name, date) => {
  cy.get(input[name="${name}"])
    .type(date)
    .should('have.value', date)
}

cy.fillDate('name', '01/01/2025')
```

Here is a full example test

```js
cy.visit('https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/getting-started/')
cy.get('input.MuiInputBase-input')
  .type('01/01/2025')
  .should('have.value', '01/01/2025')
```